# Some questions about linear model and generalized linear model (Are the process of building a model the same in these two models?)

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I am learning linear regression model from the textbook "A Second Course in Statistics: Regression Analysis （seventh edition)" by William Mendenhall and Terry Sincich.
There is a figure showing the general process of conducting a multiple linear regression:
[image]

I think this graph is well illustrated and easy to understand. But I still have some questions regarding the whole process of multiple linear regression.

1)In the book, it mentioned several variable screening methods including stepwise regression and all-possible-regression selection. Is this the process that applies to "Run the stepwise regression to determine most important x's" in the graph?

2)In chapter 7, it mentioned multicollinearity as a potential pitfall in the regression process and listed several methods to detect multicollinearity and solutions. I am wondering where do these processes apply in the graph?

3)In chapter 5, it mentioned external model validation. Cross-validation is included in this section and as far as I understand, cross-validation is to split data into a training dataset and a testing dataset. Only using training data to build the model and use the testing data to test if the model works. So should the data splitting process be put at the very beginning of the multiple regression, which means select variables using only the training dataset?
If so, it raised another question: for example, if I use k-fold validation. I read online that each fold should be used to build the model. For example, if k=3, then I will have 3 models as an outcome. If the models are different, how should I choose the final model?

4)Since I am also learning the generalized linear models, such as logistic regression and poison regression. I am wondering if this process graph applies to the generalized linear model or if it is a completely different story.

5)I am wondering if you can recommend some textbooks about the generalized linear model. I found "the second course in statistics" very beginner-friendly, but the other textbook I used for generalized linear model "An introduction to generalized linear models third edition" by Annette J. Dobson and Adrian G. Barnett is very difficult to understand as I am not in stats major or maths major and those maths are making me too confused... I would greatly appreciate you help and suggestions!!!

Comment: unfortunately, the book is (IMO) wrong. Variable screening will just give you a false sense of confidence.

Comment: They forgot to clean their data.

Comment: Hi, @JesperforPresident, should cleaning data put in front of all the steps in the graph?